# how to auto load chillbox when window ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using ChillBoxs Jquery plugin with more images on my website but when window is ready I want one of that all images load as pop up images without any clicking from visitor.

Issue I can't call one of those images for the first pop up when window has already load.

Here is my JS ChillBoxs

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/chillbox-packed.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){ 
     $('[rel$=ChillBox]').ChillBox(); 
}); 

</script> 

</head>
<body>
```

And here is images

```
<a href="images/a1.jpg" rel="ChillBox" >
    <img src="images/a1.jpg" />
</a>
<a href="images/a2.jpg" rel="ChillBox" >
    <img src="images/a2.jpg" />
</a>
<a href="images/a3.jpg" rel="ChillBox" >
    <img src="images/a3.jpg" />
</a>
<a href="images/a4.jpg" rel="ChillBox" >
    <img src="images/a4.jpg" />
</a>
<a href="images/a5.jpg" rel="ChillBox" >
    <img src="images/a5.jpg" />
</a>
```

Comment: You are assuming that people know what `Chillbox` plugin is and how it works. Provide link to documentation for this plugin as most will not be familiar with it. As with many plugins, if the features and documentation don't support what you are wanting, try another plugin that does

Comment: http://www.chillwebdesigns.co.uk/chillbox

Answer (score 0):

try adding a simple click trigger:

```
$(function(){ 
     var $chill = $('[rel$=ChillBox]')
     $chill.ChillBox(); 
     $chill.first().click();
});
```